wp_nav_menu_items callback not triggered
I display the menu so:
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary'));?>

I am trying to edit it, in my functions.php file I have:
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'custom_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);

function custom_nav_menu_items($items, $args)
{
    $items .= "<li>test</li>";

    return $items;
}

However the callback isn't being triggered.

I have tried the code it is working fine, could you please try to switch the theme on test environment, theme or plugin might be conflicting with this.
Screenshot : https://ibb.co/PNhnfxM

@NarendraSishodiya Thank you, it didnt't work with default block themes, I created a very simple theme and had to check "primary" for the menu and now it works.

Glad to know your issue has been resolved.
